# Trent Richardson's jQuery timepicker initialize values

Tags: jquery

I'm using trentrichardson's jquery timepicker I found at http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

It's all working perfectly, except one little thing.  I am using the timepicker on all fields that has the id starting with 'day_in'.

```
$('input[id^="day_in"]').timepicker({
    hourGrid: 5,
    minuteGrid: 10,
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT'
});
```

If I first load the page and manually set the value of the field to something like '03:24 AM', the timepicker that appears when clicking on the field does not reflect that time in the sliders.  Instead, both sliders for hours and minutes are at the far left (12:00 AM). Is there a way to have it show the correct slider positions when first loading the page with set values?

Solved. (See comment)

Answer (score 0):

Oops, disregard my question.  I was initializing the fields without leading 0's for single digit hours.